# How get body of message in wcf inspector

Tags: wcf, text, inspector

I need monitoring response of service, I get body with method `GetReaderAtBodyContents()`, but when WCF send error message, body can't read because message haven't `xmlelement("Text cannot be written outside the root element.")`? I saw that text can't have `<binary>`. Who know have get body of error message?

Answer (score 1):

Format of message is RAW, and i read body:

```
var bodyReader = message.GetReaderAtBodyContents();
            bodyReader.ReadStartElement("Binary");
            var bodyBytes = bodyReader.ReadContentAsBase64();
            writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(ms);
            writer.WriteStartElement("Binary");
            writer.WriteBase64(bodyBytes, 0, bodyBytes.Length);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.Flush();
            ms.Position = 0;
            reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader(ms, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);
            body = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bodyBytes);
            ms.Position = 0;
            newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, message.Version);
            CopyMessagePropertiesAndHeaders(message, newMessage);
            message = newMessage;
```

But if return error message, GetReaderAtBodyContents() raise error, because message have not xmlelement `<Binary>`, how resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://wcfpro.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/catching-the-real-exception/

Comment: wcf return reply.IsFault = false